# How to avoid adding duplicate entries in an arraylist of Item of office365 folders

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I used `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item;`
in `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService`.

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, you could just use the data structure that is designed for that case: a `java.util.Set`

Comment: I would either use a Set. Or do it yourself by scanning for the item before adding it ( which is a bad practice ).

Answer (score 1):

Use java.util.Set clas instead of list.

```
Set items = new HashSet<Item>();
```

Set is the collection of unique values.